# Omega-3 from farmed sardines

Tags: diet, fish, omega-3, omega-6

I found the following post on a food-related forum ([here](http://www.marksdailyapple.com/forum/thread10121.html#post141067)):

> Farmed fish do have omega 3 in them. They have a chunk of omega 6 too
>   so while they do have omega 3, they're not ideal for normalizing the
>   ratio. However there is a case in which sardine flesh is being sold
>   after the omega 3 has been extracted to make sardine oil. A good rule
>   of thumb is that the saturated fat should be about a quarter or less
>   of of the total fat if the tin doesn't specifically say that it has
>   omega 3. If saturated fat is a higher percentage of the sardine, the
>   omega 3 has been removed.

Is this information accurate?

Comment: While I think there are some good questions here, by having four different questions in your post makes it very broad. To avoid having it closed for that reason, I would suggest you narrow down which question you want answered, and combine/make other question posts for the remaining.

Comment: @JohnP ok, thanks, I will separate the questions.